# Stop repeating image when usung graphics.DrawImage

Tags: c#, graphics, drawimage

I am trying to merge two images and show them on pictureBox but when I show any image small then the size of pictureBox it repeats

I am using this to merge with other image

```
grfx = Graphics.FromImage(Image1); // Grass.png
grfx.DrawImage(Image2,0,0);        // Mario.png
```

Here is the result
[Output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQEOL.png)

In the picture I want Mario to show only once.
Thanks,

Comment: Maybe you should add the whole code, because I tried and worked fine for me. You may also upload the input images, and list the components on your form.

Comment: We clearly need to see more code! Looking closely at the image I see that you have one Mario at the bottom, then the grass and then the second Mario. This means most likely that Image1 is already not just grass. Or that you have added someting to the BackgroundImage of the PB. Do show us more! -  Did you screencapture it or save Image1 to disk or how did you create the image we see???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself with some hint from little hint found on internet. Problem was that I changed

```
pictureBox.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Tile
```

to

```
pictureBox.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.none
```

btw thanks for you intrest.